# It says: "error: not a statement", I don't know what to do

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
 @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
```

This code is at the bottom of my MainActivity and "savedInstanceState" is marked red, as an error

Comment: Line should be: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

Answer (score 3):

Remove extra **";"** after `protected void onCreate;` and `(Bundle)savedInstanceState) ;` and end it with **"}"**

Your `onCreate` method should look like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //your Code here...
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: But "savedInstanceState" is still red

Comment: Compare my answer with your code, there is also extra **"("** in your code `((Bundle)savedInstanceState)`,,, it must be `(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: My code now is:                                                                          
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

Comment: What you mean by doesn't work? what exactly is not working? if you have error try editing the question and post the whole code

Comment: I just edited my question, this is my code, which is apparently wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code.. it is in proper syntax. put your logic inside the `onCreate` method. that's all I can say from what you provided

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help, I'll look at the onCreate method.